# ¿Cómo obtener los cuartiles, percentiles y deciles de datos agupados?

Tags: r

Obtener estos datos de cualquier tipo de datos agrupados.¿Existe alguna librería que lo haga o hay que crear la función?

Answer (score 5):

Las 4 forma de observar una distribución pueden calcularse con una función base de R: [`quantile()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html). Veamos cada caso:

#### Cuartiles

```
# generamos 1000 observaciones de 1 a 100
data <- as.integer(runif(min=0, max=100, n=1000))

quantile(data)
```

Sin parámetros `quantile` nos retorna los cuartiles, que podemos verificar invocandola con el parámetro `prob` pasandole un vector con los puntos de cada cuartil

```
quantile(data, prob=c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1))
quantile(data, prob=seq(0, 1, 1/4)) # También
```

En ambos casos, podremos observar que el resultado es el mismo:

```
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0   24   50   75   99
```

---

#### Terciles

```
 quantile(data, prob=seq(0,1,1/3))
```

---

#### Deciles

Misma función, pero variamos el parámetro `prob`

```
# deciles
quantile(data, prob=seq(0, 1, length = 11))

  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
   0    8   19   30   40   50   62   71   80   90   99
```

Con `seq(0, 1, length = 11)` establecemos los puntos deciles: `[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0`

---

#### Percentiles

Ya vimos que todo pasa por variar el vector de probabilidades, por lo que los percentiles los calculamos generar un vector de 0 a 1 haciendo `seq(0, 1, length = 101)` algo así:

```
[1] 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 ...
...
[91] 0.90 0.91 0.92 0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1.00
```

Finalmente:

```
quantile(data, prob=seq(0, 1, length = 101))

   0%    1%    2%    3%    4%    5%    6%    7%    8%    9%   10%   11%   12%   13%   14%   15% 
 0.00  0.00  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  4.00  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.00  9.00 11.00 12.00 13.00 14.00 
  16%   17%   18%   19%   20%   21%   22%   23%   24%   25%   26%   27%   28%   29%   30%   31% 
15.00 16.00 17.00 18.00 19.00 20.00 21.00 23.00 23.76 24.00 25.00 26.00 27.00 29.00 30.00 30.00 
  32%   33%   34%   35%   36%   37%   38%   39%   40%   41%   42%   43%   44%   45%   46%   47% 
32.00 32.00 33.00 34.00 35.00 36.00 37.62 39.00 40.00 41.00 42.00 43.00 44.56 45.00 47.00 47.53 
  48%   49%   50%   51%   52%   53%   54%   55%   56%   57%   58%   59%   60%   61%   62%   63% 
48.00 49.00 50.00 51.00 53.00 54.00 56.00 57.00 58.00 59.00 59.42 61.00 62.00 62.00 63.00 64.00 
  64%   65%   66%   67%   68%   69%   70%   71%   72%   73%   74%   75%   76%   77%   78%   79% 
64.36 65.00 66.00 67.33 69.00 70.00 71.00 72.00 73.00 74.00 75.00 75.00 77.00 78.00 79.00 79.00 
  80%   81%   82%   83%   84%   85%   86%   87%   88%   89%   90%   91%   92%   93%   94%   95% 
80.00 81.00 82.00 82.17 84.00 85.00 86.00 87.00 88.00 89.00 90.00 91.00 92.00 93.00 94.00 94.00 
  96%   97%   98%   99%  100% 
95.00 96.00 97.00 98.00 99.00
```

---

**Nota**: En todas las salidas los valores `0%` y `100%` representan el valor mínimo y máximo de la muestra.

Comment: Es posible hacer mismos cálculos pero en base a un factor dentro del dataset?

Comment: un quantil, percentil, etc  solo es aplicable a variables continuas.  ¿a que te refieres con un factor?

Comment: Lo que quise decir es que si tengo una variable y (continua) pero mi dataset contiene categorias. Por ejemplo A=y1,y2,y3. Y B=, y3, y10, y11. Quisiera los cuantiles de la variable y pero para A y B separadamente.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok. te entendí. Si, tienes que agrupar los datos y por cada categoría calcular los quantiles, una forma simple, e adaptar este ejemplo `aggregate(disp ~ cyl, mtcars, quantile)`, en tu caso `cyl` sería la variable `factor` y `disp` la variable continua

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, siempre son my utiles tus comentarios. Una ultima consula si puede ser. Quiero que le categorice la variable disp en base a los percentiles que estoy calculando (que son variables segun cyl). Podrás orientarme? No logro encontrar esto

Comment: Hola @Calfiao, ahora no te sigo, por que no armas una pregunta mejor? con gusto la miro después.